# Properties of the function satisfying this equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the following differential equation. I have no idea how to solve it. So I put the equation in Maple hoping for a solution but it does not give any. Can I have some help with the differential equation to find $f(x,y)$ or atleast guessing the properties function $f(x,y)$
\begin{equation}
x\partial f(x,y) + f(x,y)= 4x^2\partial f(x,y) +2xf(x,y) +x^3y(x^2\partial^3f(x,y) +5x^2\partial^2f(x,y)+4\partial f(x,y)) 
\end{equation}

$\partial^n=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}$

My differential equation does not have the term $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ so it's like treating $y$ as a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward approach to getting information on $f(x,y)$ would be to substitute a series expansion, i.e. using the [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method). However, as it turns out, your differential equation has a so-called *irregular singularity* at the origin.

You can still try to solve equations of this type using a series expansion approach. Moreover, most information you can find on these approaches are for equations of order 2, whereas your equation is of order 3. For more information about linear differential equations of arbitrary order, and how to treat irregular singularities in those, see the appropriate [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.8#i) section. To see how a second order equation with irregular singularities can be solved, see again [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.7#i).

Comment: So you are treating $y$ as a constant and hence I can use the reference you mentioned? Thanks for that.

Comment: Exactly, you can treat $y$ as a parameter. Feel free to accept the answer, btw :-)